# An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the AssumeRole operation

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-iam, assume-role

I have a lambda function (***lambda-get-details***) created using the below IAM role in ***Account-A***

**Role name**: ***lambdarole***

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Action": [
                "logs:CreateLogGroup",
                "logs:CreateLogStream",
                "logs:PutLogEvents"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:logs:*:*:*",
            "Effect": "Allow"
        },
        {
            "Action": [
                "config:PutEvaluations",
                "ec2:DescribeImages",
                "sts:AssumeRole"
            ],
            "Resource": "*",
            "Effect": "Allow"
        }
    ]
}
```

The same IAM role name (***lambdarole***) is created in different accounts as well like ***Account-B***

Now the lambda function from ***Account-A*** needs to get details from ***Account-B*** for example (List of AMI's) and we are getting the below error

```
"errorMessage": "An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the AssumeRole operation: User: arn:aws:sts::Account-A:assumed-role/lambdarole/lambda-get-details is not authorized to perform: sts:AssumeRole on resource: arn:aws:iam::Account-B:role/lambdarole
```

Can someone help me solving the above issue.

Any help would be appreciated

Thanks

Comment: Did you add `Account-A` as the trusted account for the role in `Account-B`?

Comment: @franklinsijo No, I have not added Account-A as the trusted account for the role in Account-B

Comment: Error message says User: arn:aws:sts::Account-A:assumed-role/lambdarole/lambda-get-details is not authorized to perform: sts:AssumeRole on resource: arn:aws:iam::Account-B:role/lambdarole

Comment: Trust relationship is not established between the accounts, without it AssumeRole cannot be done.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In **Account-A**, the policy of `lambdarole` allows role assumption to any role ARN's (including roles in **Account-B**). This is taken care by this statement

```
       {
            "Action": [
                "sts:AssumeRole"
            ],
            "Resource": "*",
            "Effect": "Allow"
        }
```

Similarly in **Account-B**, the role `lambdarole` should contain a trust policy which allows role assumption from **Account-A**.

Add the `AccountID` or the `lambdarole` Role ARN of **Account-A** as the Principal in the **Account-B**'s `lambdarole`'s AssumeRolePolicyDocument.

The `AssumeRolePolicyDocument` would look like this (if account ID is used as Principal),

```
"AssumeRolePolicyDocument": {
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect" : "Allow",
            "Action": "sts:AssumeRole",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS" : "<Account-ID-of-Account-A>"                                
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

You can refer [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/tutorial_cross-account-with-roles.html) to understand how cross account access is established with IAM roles.

Comment: Thanks for providing a solution. The (lambdarole) is deployed on all the accounts. If we modify our role (lambdarole) with the (AssumeRolePolicyDocument) which you have suggested, it would get deployed to all the accounts as well as on Account-A in which the lambda is deployed. Do you see any problems if it happens to be deployed on the Account-A as well?

Comment: The `AssumeRolePolicyDocument` must be modified accordingly based on the deployed account. No issues if it gets deployed on Account-A, it is not going to add any harm if an account is allowed to trust itself to assume a role.

Comment: Quick question: Is the AssumeRolePolicyDocument valid since we have not defined any service in it?

Comment: It has account instead of service.

Comment: Thank You. Do you have any reference documentation link, so that I can go through it.

Comment: Also, I am adding the lambdarole Role ARN of Account-A as the Principal in the Account-B's lambdarole's AssumeRolePolicyDocument.

Comment: This [document](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/tutorial_cross-account-with-roles.html) will be explanatory.

Answer (score 1):

If your account has MFA then there is additional config need to put in the profile :

```
mfa_serial = arn:aws:iam::<serial>:mfa/<username>
```

you should be able to find the complete value of the arn in security credentials of user detail of your account.